# R function for percentage changes of price

Tags: r

I have a real big problem.
I am using RSTUDIO and my task is to find a percentage change of the Average price to the previous day.

Created a new column PercantageCh and I can add value by myself

```
bitcoin$PercentageCh[3] <- round((bitcoin$AverageP[3]-bitcoin$AverageP[2])/bitcoin$AverageP[2]*100, 3)
```

How to automize this process for all 2014 rows? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sample data:

```
bitcoin <- data.frame(AverageP = c(431.8805, 433.9660, 429.2245, 431.8005))
```

Using a custom function:

```
pct_change <- function(x){
  round((x - dplyr::lag(x))/dplyr::lag(x)*100,3)
}


bitcoin$PercentageCh <- pct_change(bitcoin$AverageP)
```

Gives us:

```
  AverageP PercentageCh
1 431.8805           NA
2 433.9660        0.483
3 429.2245       -1.093
4 431.8005        0.600
```

Comment: Thanks for noting that. I specified `dplyr::lag`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `diff`:

```r
c(NA, diff(bitcoin$AverageP)) / bitcoin$AverageP
# [1]           NA  0.004805676 -0.011046667  0.005965718
c(NA, diff(bitcoin$AverageP) / bitcoin$AverageP[-nrow(bitcoin)])
# [1]           NA  0.004828882 -0.010925971  0.006001521
```

(using Matt's `bitcoin` definition).

Use whichever version depending on whether it is percentage change relative to the previous or the next value. (Notice the parentheses and what is under the `/`-operator, it is different between the two.)

Comment: It's great that `diff` doesn't need any other package.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dplyr::lag`,

```
bitcoin$PercentageCh <- round((bitcoin$AverageP-lag(bitcoin$AverageP))/lag(bitcoin$AverageP)*100, 3)
```

I was wrong with location of `lag`

## Difference between `dlpyr::lag` and `stats::lag`

```
bitcoin <- data.frame(
  AverageP = rnorm(10)
)
bitcoin$PercentageCh <- round((bitcoin$AverageP-dplyr::lag(bitcoin$AverageP))/dlpyr::lag(bitcoin$AverageP)*100, 3)
bitcoin

     AverageP PercentageCh
1   2.1972088           NA
2   1.4049739      -36.056
3   0.5074163      -63.884
4  -1.4304888     -381.916
5   0.1726630     -112.070
6  -0.9722128     -663.070
7  -0.1076338      -88.929
8   1.1585936    -1176.421
9  -0.2636449     -122.756
10 -1.5825011      500.240

    bitcoin$PercentageCh <- round((bitcoin$AverageP-stats::lag(bitcoin$AverageP))/stats::lag(bitcoin$AverageP)*100, 3)
    bitcoin

     AverageP PercentageCh
1   2.1972088            0
2   1.4049739            0
3   0.5074163            0
4  -1.4304888            0
5   0.1726630            0
6  -0.9722128            0
7  -0.1076338            0
8   1.1585936            0
9  -0.2636449            0
10 -1.5825011            0
```

Comment: I got 0 in each PercentageCh row

Comment: Likely because you have not loaded `dplyr`; change `lag` to `dplyr::lag` if you have it installed.

Comment: @a_mukhamedshin You may need to install and load `dplyr` package. I add difference between `stats::lag` and `dplyr::lag`.